# Does An "include" file that's a mile long slow page speed?

Tags: php, performance

I'm always looking for ways I can improve my site's pages load times (which they're not bad to start with) and I'm new to PHP and advanced coding practices so I come with a very unique question;

If I'm building a page (or site) and I am using includes and at the beginning of the template is a call to a file which houses a LOT of the functions used throughout the site, and I'm wondering if this page that goes for a while which lists all my site's functions is slowing the page load speed?

The way I see it, the browser has to read all of that everytime a page is loaded??

Seems to me my concern WOULD slow page speed but then again what do I know??

I'm very novice and am not aware of how fast a computer can "Read" all of this and if anyone wouldn't mind sharing their thoughts on this I'd certainly welcome your input and I thank you in advance.)

Comment: Yes, it does slow down the page like that. And yes, the computer does this so fast that you won't be able to see the slowdown by eye but it's still there. This specific problem is what *opcode caches* are meant to combat.

Comment: looks like... not so much . [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885332/does-reading-include-files-slow-down-php-script-load)

Comment: Hi @Jon, Thanks for your reply. Would you say it's worthwhile to break up the functions? (ie: create smaller files of functions that are only used by specific pages)

Comment: BTW, My present functions file is ~300 lines

Comment: @StuartKaufman: In general yes, but it doesn't really matter unless your site starts getting hundreds of hits per second. However, splitting functions into files and juggling the dependencies manually is very hard and error prone; that's why we put the functions into classes and use [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to automatically load only those classes that a script requires.

Comment: Breaking down the file won't help... if anything it might hurt (technically, although a minuscule amount).  Check my answer for a work-around.

Comment: @StuartKaufman: 300 lines is nothing. At 30000 lines (figure of speech) we might start talking about it.

Comment: does your include have php or javascript?

Answer (score 2):

It absolutely would slow down the page load.  However, if you're using Javascript in this website then you could do an AJAX load of the code.  In jQuery you could do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('myURL.php', function(data) {
        $("#myDiv").html(data);
    });
});
```

What this code does is wait until the document has completely loaded (`$(document).ready()`) then it makes an AJAX 'GET' request to the specified URL and returns the data which is outputted at that URL all in the background completely absent of the rest of the HTML rendering on the screen.  The great thing about using AJAX is that it will fire when you tell it to, so the loading of the front-end of your page won't 'hang' on that `include('myURL.php')` call.

This solution allows you to get your HTML rendered on the screen without users having to sit at a white screen waiting for the `include()` call to happen.  Instead they can view the website and interact with it and then script loads in the background after everything is rendered.  If you wanted to let people know that information is being loaded in the background then maybe include a AJAX loader graphic in that spot on the page.

Comment: Ya'll Are Awesome!! I Thank Each of You Very Much!!

Comment: Totally man, welcome to Stack Overflow, glad to be of any help!  If you like any answer you see then you should upvote and mark it correct so others can see what helped you if they encounter a similar issue.

Comment: This can be a useful way to load slow data, but be careful with this approach as anyone with JS disabled won't see that part of the page. The other concern is server load since each page load will actually trigger two or more full HTTP requests, which can cause far more slowdowns for everyone instead of just the one user.